# CakePHP youtube video not showing

Tags: cakephp

I have took youtube video url and add it in database.Here is youtube share code

```
<iframe width="99%" height="390" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Tj34AZuGgEs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In php it is showing well.Here is my php code

```
 <div id="video">
      <?php echo $row['video_url'];  ?>
  </div>
```

Here it is working fine.In cakephp I have used console for generate code.Here video not showing,it is showing direct url same as database table.

Here is cakephp code

```
<dt><?php echo __('Video Url'); ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php echo h($video['Video']['video_url']); ?>
            &nbsp;
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

How can I see the video not video source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use without [**h** function](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/function-h.html) `<?php echo $video['Video']['video_url']; ?>`